# The form of the distribution of a test statistic

Tags: distributions, matlab

I have certain statistic $T$ for a likelihood ratio test, and I want to know how its the distribution behave (its form), so I did a simulation:

1- I created a loop and I simulated my data, and placed the values of $T$ in a vector $Y$ (number of values calculated is let's say 100).

2- I created another loop contaning the first one that calculate the mean of each vector calculated in 1, and I put them into another vector $V$ (of length 500).

So my code (in Matlab) is something like:

`for j=1:500
     for i=1:100
         simulate data
         Y(i)= value of T
      end
     V(j)=mean(Y)
end`

My question is: To know how the distribution of $T$ behaves, should I plot the histogram of $V$ or $Y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see how T behaves you should plot a histogram of T. For comparison think of the Z test; if you simulated 100 Z scores you would expect that 95% of them would be in the region [-1.96,1.96]. If you got the mean of 100 Z scores it would be pretty close to 0, but usually 1.96 is the critical value of Z so the averages of many Z scores don't tell you anything useful about where your test statistic will lie.

Also remember that the distribution of T will vary depending on the size of your data so when simulating T you should simulate it for the same amount of data as your sample size.

Comment: So I should be working with $Y$ instead of $W$, since the values of $T$ are stored into $Y$,

Comment: Yes that's correct. The values of T are what you should be examining